# Color separation in projector

Tags: projector

I have a projector whose display's colors are separating.  So there is a ghost red image shifted up and left, and a ghost blue image shifted down and right.  The "replace lamp" light was on, so I replaced the lamp and the image is much brighter.  However, we're still getting a shift in the colors.  Any ideas on how I can rectify this?  It's a Sanyo PLC-XP30.

We already unplugged/replugged the VGA cables on both ends, and verified the problem does not manifest when using a monitor.  We haven't tried replacing the cable yet, but that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LCD panel is probably out of alignment. This is generally something that would be corrected in a service center, although in some high-end projectors there may be a menu interface to calibrate the mechanism (I've only seen this on theater systems, though). I would definitely look through the manual and see if it says anything about alignment or calibration. If it doesn't, contact Sanyo to see what they would charge you to perform the calibration. This is not something the manufacturer would recommend an end-user attempt, but (although I can't speak from experience) I suspect it's not really that difficult, there's probably a screw-based mechanism you need to adjust with a screwdriver until alignment is correct. I don't know where you could find documentation on how to get to this mechanism, though.